# Code element with HTML and CSS destroy my Shopping World in Shopware

Tags: html, css, navigationbar, shopware

I created new Shopping World in Shopware 5, and I inserted Code element with next HTML and CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
         
    <style>
         ul {
           list-style: none;
           margin: 0 auto;
           width: 100%;
           position: fixed;
           top: 107px;
           left: 497px;      
       }
       ul li {
           float: left;
           padding-bottom: 0;
       }
       ul a {
           display: block;
           text-align: center;
           color: black;
           text-decoration: none;
           font-family: 'couture', serif;
           padding: 6px 23px;
           background: white;
           font-size: 12pt;
       }
        ul li#active a {
            border-bottom: 4px solid black;
            color: black;
            padding-bottom: 23px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <ul> 
        <li id="active"><a href="">Mens</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Women</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem is in Shopware 5, but I'm a new with Shopware, and I'm very confused. This code just destroy my Shopping World, I don't know why? This is very simple small navigation menu with underline. I need someone who know what's happening with Shopware.
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Are you really supposed to insert a _complete_ HTML document in that place …? I don’t know shopware, but usually these kind of systems allow you to embed HTML _snippets_ in certain places, that will then be rendered inside the full page template provided by the system ...

Comment: What you mean is that menu is so much to the left?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put html/css into shopping world.
You should create your custom emotion element, check this guide:
https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/custom-shopping-world-elements/

Comment: In Shopping World there is "Code element" just for insert HTML, CSS and JS code into Shopping World page. 
But, when I put code, Shopping world is acting strange. He goes crazy. I hew new elements like new strange menu, lines, etc.

Comment: Probably because you are inserting html, head, and body tags into the "code element" and that's causing conflicts because you actually already have those tags, so you only need to write the html you need, in this case the <ul>...</ul>